# how to change the width of jssor thumbnail navigator

Tags: jquery, html, jssor

I'm trying to use the jssor transition library to have my images displaying with thumbnail navigators.

I've seen their demos and have tried to change some of the settings to change the width of the navigation bar while its in vertical mode but i cant seem to target the blank space inside of it.

Everything i've done changes the image size of the thumbnail itself, even when getting the element with chromes developer tools, i cant change the width of the element.

I have attached an image to show what i mean about the blank space.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9LXH.jpg

What is the correct way to manipulate the width of this navigator bar so i can stop having black spaces around the thumbnails?

Comment: Which thumbnail skin do you use?

Comment: im using the template found in the slider pack, under "demos-jquery", file "image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnails.source".
I've tried modifying that example as well but i cant figure out what actually changes the width of the navigator section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what your mean exactly.

Note that the slider is with 'outer container', 'slides container' and 'thumbnail navigator container'.
'slides container' and 'thumbnail navigator container' is in the 'outer container'.

You have something right. Next you just need to adjust size of 'outer container', and adjust position of 'slides container'

Comment: ahhhh yes i see, so by making the width of the outer container smaller, making the "left" position of the slides container smaller and the width of the thumbnavigator container, ive finally made the black space smaller. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please change the size of thumbnail navigator element,

```
<div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort02" style="position: absolute; width: 240px; height: 480px; left:0px; bottom: 0px;">
```

Comment: thanks for the rreply, the thing is i have tried changing the width of the thumbnail navigator and this is what i get,
http://imgur.com/IIejnLZ
i cant get the black parts around the thumbnail icons to resize to be narrower. This is when i dont change anything else apart from the "width" property to 100px from 240px. Is there something else i should be changing?

Answer (score 0):

There are some options to do this job, like $SpacingX, $SpacingY,

```
            $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable thumbnail navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

                $ActionMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
                $Lanes: 2,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange thumbnails, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 14,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 12,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $Cols: 6,                             //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
                $Align: 156,                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
                $Orientation: 2                                //[Optional] Orientation to arrange thumbnails, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            }
```

Comment: i have tried all those as well, ive made lanes = 1, removed spacing of x and tried setting it to 0, tried moving the parking position to be +500, and -500, set orientation to 1 (which makes the navigator horizontal, and the navigator is still on the left side of the screen) and played with all the styling on thumbnavigator but the width still does not change,. After fiddling with all the controls and styling, i still cannot figure out how to modify the space where the navigator should be.
I have linked to shows what it currently does and what i want to achieve: http://imgur.com/a/wnmkM#0